# Filtering a datasource on Click Event

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, filter

I have a datasource which is specified on Page_Load :

```
     // EmpDetailsList query to get employee data

     EmpGridView.DataSource = EmpDetailsList
     EmpGridView.DataBind()
```

I am trying to filter the datasource when the user clicks a button;

```
 Protected Sub Search_btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Search_btn.Click    

    FilteredList = EmpDetailsList.Where(EmpDetailsList.FirstName= "John")

    EmpGridView.DataSource = FilteredList
    EmpGridView.DataBind()

End Sub
```

I am having a lot of trouble doing this without using *EmpDetailsList* as a global variable.

I also do not want to violate the DRY principle and call the data source a second time when the search button is clicked. I also tried passing *EmpDetailsList* as a parameter to another Sub but I don't understand how to use it with a click event handler.

Any suggestions will be helpful, I've looked for a couple of hours but I haven't found anything that doesn't use global variables.

Comment: The data has to live somewhere, and I'm not sure that having data live in a DB and querying it without a where clause then later querying it with a where clause qualifies as "repeating yourself" / violates DRY. What would you prefer; to have the server remember 20,000 rows and filter them if the user comes back with a search query? Or have the db retain the data and you query it appropriately. I pick the latter. A server memory/user session is not a db

Comment: @CaiusJard related to your comment, then would you say that it is also inappropriate to use a view state to update records in the grid view and save the update to the DB? Just weighing my options. But yes I see your point about the querying.

Answer (score 0):

The `Where` function expects a predicate. Add a `.ToList` at the end so your have a `List(Of T)` instead of an `IEnumerable`.

```
Protected Sub Search_btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Search_btn.Click
    Dim FilteredList = (EmpDetailsList.Where(Function(e) e.FirstName = "John")).ToList
    EmpGridView.DataSource = FilteredList
    EmpGridView.DataBind()
End Sub
```